# Angular's $anchorScroll not playing nicely with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, anchor-scroll

I've got an app which reveals data (`ng-show`) from a JSON file once a button is clicked.

What i'm having trouble with is the anchorScroll, which will only scroll to the anchor once the button has been clicked **twice**. I need it to work on the first click.

here is where the magic is supposed to happen, but doesn't

```
var onSearchComplete = function(results){
            $scope.showResults = true; //ng-show listens for this to be true
            $scope.results = results;

            $timeout(function() {
                $location.hash('resultsAnchor');
                $anchorScroll();
            });
        };
```

Here's what i know:

- *first click*: initially my URL starts of as `url/#/`, then when button is clicked,
  `#resultsAnchor` is appended so my URL is now `url/#/#resultsAnchor`.
  The `ng-show div` with my data will appear for an instance then
  disappear. No anchorScroll occurs as data is not there.
- now my URL is set to `url/#/#resultsAnchor`, and on *second click* the
  ng-show div appears and the page scrolls to the data.

What is it that is stopping this happen in one click?

note: i added the $timeout function because otherwise it would take three clicks. click 1 - anchor is appended to url, click 2 - data appears, click 3 - page scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue, and it was corrected by adding the location's prefix to the hash.

```
location.hash = '/details#memberTop';
$anchorScroll();
```

which ends up navigating to:

url/#/details#memberTop